# function returns address of local variable, but it still compile in c, why?

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-errors, x86, undefined-behavior

Even I get an *warning* a function returns an address from local variable, it compiles. Isn't it then UB of compiler? The generated assembly:

```
    .text
.LC0:
    .asciz "%i\n"
    .globl  foo
    .type   foo, @function
foo:
    pushq   %rbp    #
    movq    %rsp, %rbp  #,
    sub     $16, %rsp   #,
    mov     %rdi, -8(%rbp)   #,
    leaq    -8(%rbp), %rax   #,
# a.c:5: }
    leave 
    ret
    .size   foo, .-foo
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    pushq   %rbp    #
    movq    %rsp, %rbp  #,
# a.c:8:    foo();
    movl    $123, %edi  #,
    call    foo #
    movq    (%rax), %rsi   #,
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdi   #,
    movl    $0, %eax   #,
    call    printf #,
    movl $0, %eax
# a.c:9: }
    popq    %rbp    #
    ret 
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Here the assmebly is returning an address of local variable `leaq -8(%rbp), %rax`, but then it calls instrution `leave`, which should "invalidate" the address `-8(%rbp)` (the stack pointer is added, so the I should be no longer be able to dereference that address, since the program moved on). So why it compile, and happily dereference the `mov (%rax), %rdi`, when the address retunred to `%rax` is no longer valid? Should not it segfault or terminate?

Comment: Maybe because this specific part of the stack has not changed and is still readable. This could happen but is is not guaranteed . edit: wait, still compile or still run?? compiling such program is not invalid in c. remember that a pointer is just a number. Its not up to the compiler to decide weather it is acceptable or not memory, it would be a runtime error. despite this, the compiler detected the error and raised a warning

Comment: @avivgood2 no, the program should terminated. The compiler should not be able to return any invalid address to be reused later. I though `gcc` is more mature to avoid this runtime-errors

Comment: @milanHrabos use `gcc  -Werror ....` when you compile your code

Comment: @P__J__ I do not ignore warning, that's the reason I give this post. One thing is gcc warnings and information about what is wrong and should be fixed, but the other thing is the compiler itself will handle it. And dereferencing **any** address (becuase If compiler can dereference a invalid address from stack, then it could dereference any address it wants huh?), is just no right. The compiler should be able to do this

Comment: It's not the compiler's job to avoid UB. It is your's. The compiler is allowed to assume you are doing things right and does not need to take extra measures to stop you from doing evil things.

Comment: @P__J__: there's no need to be so hostile and extrapolate from this misunderstanding to "you are a bad programmer".  That's just not a helpful thing to say, and not enough information to draw that conclusion.  This is a person who posted a poor question (no [mcve], *just* the asm output, so readers can't easily go look for themselves on Godbolt), and suffers from the common misconception that UB = required to fail.  That's all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Even I get an warning a function returns an address from local
> variable, it compiles. Isn't it then UB of compiler?

No, but if it were, how could you tell?  You seem to have a misunderstanding of undefined behavior.  It does not mean "the compiler must reject it", "the compiler must warn about it", "the program must terminate", or any such thing.  Those indeed *may* be a manifestations of UB, but if the language specification required such behavior then it wouldn't be *undefined*.  **Ensuring that a C program does not exercise undefined behavior is the responsibility of the programmer, not the C implementation.**  Where a programmer does not fulfill that responsibility, the C implementation explicitly has no reciprocal responsibility -- it can do anything within its capabilities.

Moreover, there is no single "the" C compiler.  Different compilers may do things differently and still conform to the C language specifications.  This is where implementation-defined, unspecified, and undefined behaviors come in.  Allowing such variance is intentional on the part of the C language designers. Among other things, it allows implementations to operate in ways that are natural for their particular target hardware and execution environments.

Now let's go back to "no".  Here is a prototypical example of a function returning the address of an automatic variable:

```
int *foo() {
    int bar = 0;
    return &bar;
}
```

What about that is supposed to have undefined behavior?  It is well defined for the function to compute the address of `bar`, and the resulting pointer value has the correct type to be returned by the function.  After `bar`'s lifetime ends when the function returns, the return value becomes indeterminate (paragraph 6.2.4/2 of the standard), but that does not in itself give rise to any undefined behavior.

Or consider a caller:

```
void test1() {
    int *bar_ptr = foo();  // OK under all circumstances
}
```

As already discussed, our particular `foo()`'s return value will always be indeterminate, so in particular, it might be a trap representation.  But that's a runtime consideration, not a compile-time one.  And even if the value were a trap representation, C does not require that the implementation refuse or fail to store it.  In particular, footnote 50 to C11 is explicit on this point:

> Thus, an automatic variable can be initialized to a trap
> representation without causing undefined behavior, but the value of
> the variable cannot be used until a proper value is stored in it.

Note also that `foo()` and `test1()` can be compiled by different runs of the compiler, such that when compiling `test1()`, the compiler knows nothing about the behavior of `foo()` beyond what is indicated by its prototype.  C does not place translation-time requirements on implementations that depend on the runtime behavior of programs.

On the other hand, the requirements around trap representations would apply differently if the function were modified slightly:

```
void test2() {
    int *bar_ptr = NULL;
    bar_ptr = foo();      // UB (only) if foo() returns a trap representation
}
```

If the return value of `foo()` turns out to be a trap representation, then *storing* it in `bar_ptr` (as opposed to *initializing* `bar_ptr` with it) produces undefined behavior at runtime.  Again, however, "undefined" means just what it says on the tin.  C does not define any particular behavior for implementations to exhibit under the circumstances, and in particular, it does not require that programs terminate or manifest any externally-visible behavior at all.  And again, that's a runtime consideration, not a compile-time one.

Furthermore, if `foo()`'s return value turns out not to be a trap representation (being instead a pointer value that is not the address of any live object), then there's nothing wrong with reading that value itself, either:

```
void test3() {
    int *bar_ptr = foo();
    // UB (only) if foo() returned a trap representation:
    printf("foo() returned %p\n", (void *) bar_ptr);
}
```

The biggest and most commonly-exercised undefined behavior in this area would be that of trying to dereference the return value of `foo()`, which, trap representation or not, almost surely does not point to a live `int` object:

```
void test4() {
    int *bar_ptr = foo();
    // UB under all circumstances for the given foo():
    printf("foo() returned a pointer to an int with value %d\n", *bar_ptr);
}
```

But again, that's a runtime consideration, not a compile-time one. And again, undefined means undefined.  The C implementation should be expected to translate that successfully as long as there are in-scope declarations for the functions involved, and although some compilers might warn, they have no obligation to do so.  The runtime behavior of function `test4` is undefined, but that does not mean the program necessarily will segfault or terminate in some other manner.  It might, but I expect that in practice, the undefined behavior manifested by a great many implementations would be to print "foo() returned a pointer to an int with value 0".  Doing so is in no way inconsistent with C's requirements.

Comment: Does the Standard anywhere actually specify that initialization of an object is an exception to the requirement that the stored value of an object not be accessed (read or written) other than by use of an lvalue of an appropriate type?  Only an astoundingly obtuse compiler would use Standard's waiver of authority over program behavior in such cases as justification for not processing initialization in sane fashion, but the ability to process such constructs is a Quality of Implementation issue, rather than a conformance one.

Comment: I don't think I anywhere suggested that the Standard makes such an exception, @supercat.  I certainly did not intend to do so.  On the other hand, I did talk about the standard's provisions regarding trap representations with respect to initialization *vs* assignment, and that is accompanied by an attributed quotation of the standard.

Answer (score 4):

As you stated, if you return the address of a local variable from a function and attempt to dereference (or even read) that address, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The formal definition of **undefined behavior** is stated in section 3.4.3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or
> of erroneous data,for which this International Standard imposes no
> requirements

When undefined behavior occurs, the compiler makes no guarantees about what will happen.  The program may crash, it may output strange results, or it may appear to work properly.

Generally speaking, compilers will assume code does not contain undefined behavior and work under that assumption.  So when it does, all bets are off.

Just because the program *could* crash doesn't mean it *will*.

Comment: Once we allow compiler to dereference **any** address, then we lost the game. It is just a russian roulette, when it *will* crash. That is not just about UB anymore

Comment: @milanHrabos Again, just because it could crash doesn't mean it will.  There's no guarantee of that.

Comment: @milanHrabos no, You have to make sure that the program will not return it. C is very hard to learn for beginners because of it and we see it here very very often

Comment: @milanHrabos: If it happens to compile to asm that returns a stack address (rather than NULL like gcc / clang do with optimization when this kind of UB is visible at compile time), it won't actually segfault.  In most OSes (Linux at least), stack space never gets handed back to the OS (unmapped), so the pointer will continue pointing to a readable + writeable page.  The contents there will be garbage, and potentially overlap a local in a later function if you pass the pointer on to another call.  But it won't actually segfault.

Comment: The asm details are different from a use-after-`free`, which is likely to crash if it was a large allocation, not just kept in the free list.

Answer (score 3):

It will compile of course and some compilers will emit the diagnostic message informing you about the problem. Many compilers allows to treat such a messages (typically called warning) as errors by passing command line options.

UB means that behaviour of your program when you run it is **undefined**

Comment: And isn't it **undefined** ?? dereferencing returned address from local variable??

Comment: It is undefined - so everything may happen. segfault, nothing, correct execution, breaks fault (if it happens in the car computer), pizza order, bank transfer etc etc etc

Comment: ? What are yout talking about? Are we engineers or child ? It is not *magic*, compiler has strict rules so it has to deal with runtime errors as well.

Comment: @milanHrabos a lot of things in c are implementation - defined

Comment: @milanHrabos you can write your own compiler if you wish. C is a specific language and it makes it so powerful. If you do not like UBs - there are many high level languages which do allow them. C# Java, Pascal ADA, Python F#  etc etc

Comment: @milanHrabos The compiler does have strict rules, those laid out in the C standards. If you do something in violation of those rules, the compiler doesn't have to obey them either. See [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: @ThomasJager I don't care about nasal demos. It could be interesting for kids for good night, but not for me. I want to know how compiler truly works. If you come to talk about stories, there are other sites for it, go there.

Comment: @milanHrabos The compiler does truly work. It works exactly as specified. The existence of UB is *in no way* an issue with the compiler. If you want a language that protects you from yourself, pick another language.

Comment: @milanHrabos then do not use C. C# does exactly what you need. You have mono to run on many platforms.

Comment: @milanHrabos C is not a hand-holding language, and the compiler should not be blamed for the programmer's negligence.

Answer (score 2):

The difficulty is that the Standard strongly implies(*) that the presence of code which would invoke Undefined Behavior *if executed* should not interfere with the execution of the program in cases where that code would not be executed.  When the compiler generates code for the function, it has no idea if code that calls the function might attempt to treat the return value as an address in some fashion that would not be defined either by the Standard or by any extended semantics the implementation might offer.  For example, many implementations guarantee that if conversion from a pointer to a `uintptr_t` within the lifetime of its target yields a certain value, conversion of that pointer to `uintptr_t` will always yield that value, without regard for whether its target still exists.  Commercial compilers often abide by the philosophy that if it's remotely conceivable that a programmer might want to do something (such as converting the address of a pointer to `uintptr_t` and logging it, to allow comparison with other pointer values that were logged earlier in program execution), and there's nothing to be gained by not allowing it, the compiler may as well allow it.

(*) Under the One Program Rule, a compiler that can properly process at least one program that exercises the translation limits given in the Standard may do anything it likes when fed any other source text.  Thus, if a compiler writer thought it more useful to reject all programs meeting some criteria, despite some such programs being Strictly Conforming, than to process such programs, such behavior would not make a compiler non-conforming.  Nonetheless, the Standard elsewhere says that a program would invoke UB when given some inputs could be a correct program with fully defined behavior when given other inputs.